# Hard disk: Read-only file system and blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda (READ)

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, hardware, read-only, dmesg

I performed `dmesg --level=err` to get the errors that my disk was reporting. I got a long(LONG) list of blk_update_request: I/O error.
I'm new to Ubuntu or any Linux-based os ever, So can someone interpret the given terminal output and tell me the health of my disk and what to do about it? Thank you in advance!

```
[ 4767.244628] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 838765440 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 5446.585078] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x18800000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5446.585088] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 5446.585095] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 5446.585108] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:b8:58:8c:38/00:00:2f:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 41/40:00:58:8c:38/00:00:2f:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 5446.585113] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 5446.585117] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 5446.587251] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 792235096 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 5449.547647] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x80007000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5449.547657] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 5449.547664] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 5449.547676] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:70:58:8c:38/00:00:2f:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 41/40:00:58:8c:38/00:00:2f:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 5449.547682] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 5449.547686] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 5449.549791] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 792235096 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 5452.468874] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1c0000 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 5452.468884] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[ 5452.468891] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 5452.468904] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:a0:58:8c:38/00:00:2f:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 41/40:00:58:8c:38/00:00:2f:00:00/00 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[ 5452.468909] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 5452.468913] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[ 5452.470809] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 792235096 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

Comment: Your issue is not a Ubuntu one, but a disk/hardware issue & the OS is unimportant.   Check out the health of your drive (from the drive itself using it's SMART), eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  (which is best done from a *live* system so the disk isn't being used).  GUI tools can be used as well..   *A file-system flips from RW to RO to prevent data loss, ie. preventing risk to your data, allowing you to explore & rectify the issue (replace disk etc)*